# How am I supposed to work out how to find this minikit without resorting to a walkthrough?

Tags: lego-star-wars-3-the-clone-wars

I'm working my way through Lego Star Wars 3 trying to find all the minikits.

However, I got stuck on a couple of the RTS levels even with the minikit locator "cheat" turned on. The problem kit is located at one of the capture points where there's a piece of Lego flooring with a stud pattern on it rather than the plain ground and it gets covered by a plain stud board that normally appears when you walk over it.

The [minikit guide on IGN](http://uk.ign.com/wikis/lego-star-wars-iii-the-clone-wars/Count_Dooku:_Chapter_4_-_Minikits) for one of the levels where this occurs states:

> For the 8th Minikit, capture the northwest Separatist zone. Then build three objects in the zone, as long as they aren't built on top of the pad where the Separatist barracks are. The Minikit will appear in a crater underneath that very spot.

For all the other kits on this (and other levels) there have been fairly obvious in game clues (Jedi/Sith sparkles, character specific control panels, silver or gold Lego objects instead of plain Lego, etc) even if the actual method is somewhat convoluted, or the minikit detector cheat shows which objects you need to destroy to get the kit.

So, while there is a fairly obvious clue that *something* is at this location, how I am supposed to work out what I have to do here to get the minikit just from the in game cues?

Comment: There've been more than a few collectibles over the course of the Lego series that I have had to resort to walkthroughs (sometimes multiple for the same collectible) in order to figure out, even with cheats turned on.  I just think they don't do a particularly good job of making it easy on us players :/